# catch crash in windows

Tags: windows, debugging

I have a very short running process which is crashing on windows.  I would like to catch the crash in the debugger but windbg seems to only monitor currently running processes.  Is there a way to monitor for a crash in a named process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinDBG -I will catch all crashing instances.  If you're only interested in the dump but don't want to change default postmortem debugger, you can use AdPlus to spawn your process:

adplus -crash -o <Output Directory> -sc <command line of your process>

The dump and additional info will be written to the folder you specified.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, not on windbg. But you have other options, such as:

- using `cdb -o` and attaching to the parent process. If you installed windbg, you probably installed cdb too. With cdb you can create a crash dump that you can open with windbg. See [cdb command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539058%28VS.85%29.aspx).
- using Windbg as your postmortem debugger (by running `WinDBG -I`). If you have Visual Studio installed, you probably want to revert the default postmordem debugger later, check [here](http://www.cremarenco.com/i++/?p=21) on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio you can right-click the project and select *Debug* => *Start new instance*.